# Create an image displaying text with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, text

I basically need a tool in node.js to create an image that displays values, and which height changes according to the number of these values.

I've seen that there is Jimp or even using canvas, though i'm really not used to reading documentation and i'd like a small tutorial.

Sorry for bothering you and thank you very much !

Comment: You could use jump to generate your image with one line, and add constant to height depending on the number of line you got in your text ?

Comment: I can't find "jump" neither on the npm website nor on google.. could you please send me a link ?

Comment: auto correct "jimp" ..

Comment: You also could take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54623756/6809926

Comment: That really did help me. Thank you so much for your help!